# SDL2 Only draws entire texture rather than part of the texture like I have coded

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

For some strange reason whenever I try to split a larger image file into (in my case) a 32x32 picture, but instead I get the entire picture that seems to be squished down into 32x32(the picture as a whole). Although after playing around with the values I realized that for some reason the SDL has completely ignored my request to use the SDL_Rect source(src).
Meaning that every value that I change the source(src) rectangle to doesn't change the actual image when I run the program (even a ridiculous value).

## Sprite.h

```
#ifndef SPRITE_H_
#define SPRITE_H_

#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

struct Game;

struct Sprite
{
    //Needs to be fixed :/
    //Sprite(const std::string& filepath,int x,int y,int width, int height,Game*game);
    Sprite();
    ~Sprite();
    void Load(const std::string& filepath, int x, int y,int width,int height, Game*game);
    void Draw(Game*game);
    SDL_Rect*getDstRect(){ return &dst; }
    SDL_Rect*getSrcRect(){ return &src; }

private:
    SDL_Surface*surface = NULL;
    SDL_Texture*texture = NULL;
    SDL_Rect src;
    SDL_Rect dst;
    int img_width;
    int img_height;

};

#endif // SPRITE_H_
```

### Sprite.cpp

```
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite()
{

}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);


    surface = NULL;
    texture = NULL;
}

void Sprite::Load(const std::string& filepath, int x, int y, int width, int height, Game*game)
{
    bool success = true;
    surface = IMG_Load(filepath.c_str());
    if (surface == NULL)
    {
        game->getConsole()->Error("SPRITE::Surface Is Not Loaded");
        success = false;
    }
    else
        game->getConsole()->Text("SPRITE::Surface Is Loaded");



    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game->getRenderer(), surface);
    if (texture == NULL)
    {
        game->getConsole()->Error("SPRITE::Texture Is Not Loaded");
        success = false;
    }
    else
        game->getConsole()->Text("SPRITE::Texture is Loaded");



    dst.x = x;
    dst.y = y;
    dst.w = height;
    dst.h = height;


    src.x = 0;
    src.y = 0;
    src.w = 0;
    src.h = 0;

    SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &src.w, &src.h);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    if (success)
        game->getConsole()->Text("Loaded Sprite at " + filepath);
    else
        game->getConsole()->Error("SPRITE::Failed To Load Sprite at " + filepath);

}

void Sprite::Draw(Game*game)
{
    SDL_RenderCopy(game->getRenderer(), texture, &src,&dst);
}
```

#### Part of the Map Class

```
testPlayer.Load("bin/sprites/player.png", 200,200,32,32, game);
```

This is where I have tried to change the values of the destination(dst) rectangle after messing with the source(src) rectangle.

Comment: It can't possibly be necessary to have all that code to demonstrate the problem. Please reduce it to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'd rather see that than barely any information at all though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy

**dstrect** - the destination SDL_Rect structure or NULL for the entire rendering target. **The texture will be stretched** to fill the given rectangle.

Short version - adjust source rect to have the same width and height as destination rect, and {x, y} to have starting position of fragment you want to extract.